# ngFor increase number hour Angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

Is there any way to repeat a number pattern with ngFor ?. Let's see if I explain, what I try is to simulate the time with an interval of 15 minutes, then what I want to obtain is:

```
00:00
00:15
00:30
00:45
01:00
.
.
.
23:00
23:15
23:30
23:45
```

What I currently have is this, but I would have to make a matrix of more than one hundred elements.

html

```
<mat-select placeholder="Hora inicio" formControlName="horaInicio">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let hora of horas" [value]="hora">{{ hora }} hrs.</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

ts

```
this.horas = [
      '00:00',
      '00:15',
      '00:30',
      '00:45',
      '01:00',
      '01:15',
      '01:30',
      '01:45',
      '02:00',
      '02:15',
      '02:30',
      '02:45',
    ];
```

I wonder if there is some way to do this with ngFor?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any such feature in ngFor but you can easily repeat the pattern in TS to fill your source (horas) for ngFor. Something like this:

```
for (let h = 0; h < 24; h++) {
  const hh = h > 9 ? "" + h: "0" + h;
  for(let m = 0; m < 60; m += 15) {
    const mm = m > 9 ? "" + m: "0" + m;
    this.horas.push(`${hh}:${mm}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer keeping the programming logic in TS and use the HTML/Template for binding only.
I had a similar requirement a few days back, and I ended up creating something like below using moment:

```js
const openingHour = 0;
const closingHour = 24;
const intervals = [0, 15, 30, 45];
const timings = [];

for (let hour = openingHour; hour < closingHour; hour++) {
  intervals.forEach(interval => {
    timings.push(
      moment().set({
        hours: hour,
        minutes: interval,
        seconds: 0
      }).format('HH:mm'));
  });
}
console.log(timings)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't suggest to anyone using momentJS. the bundle size is huge. That's why developers are moving to dataFns since it's tree shaking